# sqlalchemy update didn't work

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy to perform some queries and updates, but now I have trouble with UPDATE operation , when I change the model attribute pet_time(`ins.role_time = plus_days(ins.role_time,30)`) and use session to commit , sqlalchemy didn't perform the update operation.I don't know what's going on ,can anybody help?

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    nick_name = Column(String)
    create_time = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    role_time = Column(DateTime)


# the db connection info is correct
def getDbSession():
    return Session()

def queryUserById(id):
    sess = getDbSession()
    instance = sess.query(User)\
                .filter(User.id == id)\
                .limit(1).first()
    return instance

def increaseRoleTime(id,inc=1):
    ins = queryUserById(id)
    sess = getDbSession()
    if(ins.role_time is None):
        ins.role_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    inc = inc * 30
    # ins.role_time = func.ADDDATE(ins.role_time,inc)
    ins.role_time = plus_days(ins.role_time,inc)
    sess.commit()
    return 1

# import timedelta from datetime to plus days
def plus_days(mydatetime,days):
    return mydatetime + timedelta(days=days)
```

in the function `increaseRoleTime`,I change attribute role_time and commit,but still not working.

Comment: What is `Session`? Are you sure you are not creating two separate sessions in `queryUserById` and `increaseRoleTime`?

Comment: you should create one `Session` object and work with it: pass to functions as argument, etc.

Comment: why you are returning `1` in `increaseRoleTime`?

Comment: also `.limit(1).first()` doesn't make any sense, just use `.first()`

Comment: @univerio yeah,I did created two separate sessions ,when i change to one session , it works ! thank you guys . can you tell me why ? how session work internally ?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it works as what you said,thank you , and `first()` is better  than `limit(1).first()` . I just learn python and sqlalchemy,i don't know how session works internally.

Comment: @AmyMicrogoo You can use `Session` in the way you wrote if you use `scoped_session`; it's not inherently wrong and can be better than passing the session everywhere.

Comment: in which way it's better? saves one parameters slot for something really important? i don't think that getting session on first line of functions is better than passing it to them as argument